# How to combine results from a query into columns of a new table

Tags: sql

I have a list of dates, and I am trying to find the number of expired / nearly expired and OK dates and build a new table showing these.

The easiest method for me is to simply, query my database three times and build the expected results in the my app. I am just wondering if SQL would be more cleaner.

I have only managed to produce three distinct correct results, but I need to the final result to be in it's own table.

I have a SQLFiddle showing what I have done so far
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7b1a/1

My table is

```
CREATE TABLE certificates (
    ValidTo DATETIME
);
```

Data is

```
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2019-05-12') -- expired
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2019-06-20') -- due
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2019-06-25') -- due
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2020-01-25') -- ok
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2020-03-25') -- ok
INSERT INTO certificates (ValidTo) VALUES ('2020-03-05') -- ok
```

The SQL I have come up with so far is

```
select count(*) [Expired] from certificates where ValidTo < '2019-06-12'
GO
select count(*) [Due] from certificates where ValidTo >= '2019-06-12' and ValidTo <= '2019-07-12'
GO
select count(*) [OK] from certificates where ValidTo > '2019-07-12'
```

However, this will obviously show three seperate results.

Ideally, I want each result in a column of a new table

My expected result would be

```
Expired   Due   OK
1         2     3
```

Where Expired = 1 because first SQL query returns 1

Where Due = 2 because second SQL query returns 2

Where OK = 3 because third SQL query returns 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with case when expression

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7b1a/3)**

```
select 
   count(case when ValidTo < '2019-06-12' then 1 end) as [Expired],
   count(case when ValidTo >= '2019-06-12' and ValidTo <= '2019-07-12' then 1 end) as [Due],
   count(case when ValidTo > '2019-07-12' then 1 end) as [OK]
from certificates
```

OUTPUT:

```
Expired Due OK
1       2   3
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. That is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Or, so you can run the query everyday without changes, try:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( 
    CASE validto 
      WHEN CURRENT_DATE 
      THEN 1 
    END ) AS expired
, SUM( 
    CASE 
      WHEN validto > CURRENT_DATE 
       AND validto <= TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,1,CURRENT_DATE) 
      THEN 1 
    END) AS due
, SUM( 
    CASE 
      WHEN validto > TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,1,CURRENT_DATE) 
      THEN 1 
    END) AS ok
FROM certificates;
-- out  expired | due | ok 
-- out ---------+-----+----
-- out        1 |   2 |  3
-- out (1 row)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (1 row): 4.434 ms. All rows formatted: 4.466 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted @jarlh's answer as it's smaller and easier for me to read. My actual requirement is to use the current date but I was simplifying my question as much as I could.